# Matching multiple occurrences with regex

Tags: regex

I'm building an extractor in Graylog to pull tac_plus syslog data.

I have a log:

```
<70>Oct 13 10:10:05 auth tac_plus[17354]: 2015-10-13 10:10:05 -0500#01110.10.89.1#011jmartinez#011tty132#01110.10.1.27#011stop#011task_id=146#011timezone=CDT#011service=shell#011start_time=1444747732#011priv-lvl=15#011cmd=show running-config <cr>
```

I want to extract the indvidual statements between the #011 markers. I was able to get the first section, the IP with:

```
(?<=#011)(.*?)(?=#011)
```

Now I want to extract the 'jmartinez'. I'm trying:

```
#011.*?#011(.*)(#011)
```

but it matches:

```
jmartinez#011tty132#01110.10.1.27#011stop#011task_id=146#011timezone=CDT#011service=shell#011start_time=1444747732#011priv-lvl=15
```

if i do:

```
#011.*?#011(.*)(#011tty)
```

it seems to work but i'd rather it not rely on seeing #011tty because it might be something else in another message.

what about the next one? how can I extract tty132, 10.10.1.27, stop, task_id=146, etc

any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is to use a *reluctant* quantifier (just like your working IP capture):

```
#011.*?#011(.*?)#011
```

But I would go further and capture all groups at once, eg:

```
#011(.*?)#011(.*?)#011(.*?)#011(.*?)#011(.*?)#011(.*?)#011
```

Comment: Good god. I swear I tried that. I can't capture them all at once but this helps me greatly! Thank you!

Comment: @Jose just remember that `.*` gobbles up everything it can but still match. Actually, it consumes everything to the end of the input, then back-tracks until it the following term matches something.